# Get object with the GloabId

Tags: xbim

Is it possible to find an object in an IFC file using Xbim.Essentials with the GlobalId value?
I saw this kind of code supposing I know the type...But I'd like to first find the object without knowing the type.

```
var id = "2AswZfru1AdAiKfEdrNPnu";
var theDoor = model.Instances.FirstOrDefault<IIfcDoor>(d => d.GlobalId == id);
Console.WriteLine($"Door ID: {theDoor.GlobalId}, Name: {theDoor.Name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use IIfcProduct interface from

```
Xbim.Ifc4.Interfaces
```

like:

```
var ifcProduct = model.Instances.FirstOrDefault<IIfcProduct>(d => d.GlobalId == id);
```

should work on walls, slabs, columns etc...

Comment: Yes, this will definitely work and should be accepted as an answer. Just use the inheritance hierarchy of IFC entities in the query.